# How to map a List<int> to a ModificationMapping SP for Insert in EF4?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, mapping, entity-framework-mapping

I have an entity with

```
Entity
{
    int Id;
    object otherProperties;
    List<int> ForeignIds;
}
```

I have written an Insert SP that takes:

```
@Id INT,
@ForeignId INT
```

How can I map a List to a SP for Insert for a Modification Mapping that would insert a row with the `Id` and an element from `ForeignIds` for each element in `ForeignId`?

E.g.

```
Entity(){ id=1; ForeignIds = new List<int>(){2,3};}
```

Would insert:

Id | ForeignId
1 | 2
1 | 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot map this. EF doesn't understand `List` of scalar types. You must manually iterate the list and execute stored procedure for each item in the collection. You can map the procedure as function import or execute it directly by `objectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand`.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav, what's the syntax for declaring the `param Object[]`? There's nothing in the MSDN documentation about it.

Comment: Would `objectContext.ExecuteFunction` be a better choice since the SP already exists?

Comment: You can pass array of `SqlParameter`

Comment: If you make a function import you should have a method for calling the import exposed on your context. That method internally calls `ExecuteFunction` to call an imported stored procedure.

Comment: I have updated the model from the database and included the SP and can see it in the model browser under `name.Store\Stored Procedures`, should it exist as a method on the objectContext available using dot notation?

Comment: Not yet, you must first select the procedure in the model browser and from context menu select create function import.